# How can I make blocks in different colors behind the text in C#?

Tags: c#

I need to know how you can make those block in C#?

[image]

Comment: that simply states a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it...

Comment: what do you mean out of context!

Comment: Please visit the help center and take [this tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what to ask and how.

Comment: Are you making a console application, a Windows Forms app, WPF app, web app?

Comment: MSPaint will do it?

Comment: thanks for your reply Hans, i'm making a console application

Comment: Try and find out how to set textcolor and background color for the entire text. Then split the text and color each part.

Comment: You should provide a code sample of what you have done so far... Not expecting others to predict what is your actual issue and solve it for you

Comment: you're not helping B001 whatever your name is

Comment: _you're not helping_ Ok, thank you! @Aro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a console application, which is what it *looks* like you're working with, you are looking for `Console.BackgroundColor` and `Console.ForegroundColor`:

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.Write("Red");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.Write("Green");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
    Console.WriteLine("Blue");

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.Write("Red");
    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.Write("Green");
    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
    Console.WriteLine("Blue");

    Console.ResetColor();

    Console.Write("\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

---

If you want to do a lot of this, some helper methods will come in handy:

```
    static void WriteBackColor(string text, ConsoleColor backColor)
    {
        Console.BackgroundColor = backColor;
        Console.Write(text);
    }

    static void WriteForeColor(string text, ConsoleColor foreColor)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = foreColor;
        Console.Write(text);
    }

    static void WriteColor(string text, ConsoleColor foreColor, ConsoleColor backColor)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = foreColor;
        Console.BackgroundColor = backColor;
        Console.Write(text);
    }
```

Using these cuts the original code in half:

```
static void Main()
{
    WriteForeColor("Red", ConsoleColor.Red);
    WriteForeColor("Green", ConsoleColor.Green);
    WriteForeColor("Blue\n", ConsoleColor.Blue);
    WriteColor("Red", ConsoleColor.Black, ConsoleColor.Red);
    WriteBackColor("Green", ConsoleColor.Green);
    WriteBackColor("Blue\n", ConsoleColor.Blue);

    Console.ResetColor();

    Console.Write("\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

---

To center text, you can calculate the padding needed on the left by getting the console width, subtracting the with of your text, and dividing by two. Then you can either set the cursor's left position to that amount, or add that many spaces before the text:

```
static void Main()
{
    // Get the amount of padding needed on the left
    var leftPadding = (Console.WindowWidth - "RedGreenBlue".Length) / 2;

    // Start the cursor at that position
    Console.SetCursorPosition(leftPadding, Console.CursorTop);
    WriteForeColor("Red", ConsoleColor.Red);
    WriteForeColor("Green", ConsoleColor.Green);
    WriteForeColor("Blue\n", ConsoleColor.Blue);

    // Or, pad the left with spaces
    Console.Write(new string(' ', leftPadding));
    WriteColor("Red", ConsoleColor.Black, ConsoleColor.Red);
    WriteBackColor("Green", ConsoleColor.Green);
    WriteBackColor("Blue\n", ConsoleColor.Blue);

    Console.ResetColor();

    Console.Write("\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sure, have fun! I added some helper methods that might come in handy.

Comment: how do i adjust a text? lets say in the middle of the console

Comment: You can just get the width of the console, subtract the length of your text, divide by two, then either set the cursor to that position or add that many spaces before the text. I added a code sample that describes both ways.

Answer (score 0):

For a console app, this should get you started

```
  static void Main()
  {
        ConsoleColor savedBackground = Console.BackgroundColor;
        ConsoleColor savedForeground = Console.ForegroundColor;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        Console.Write("Blue");
        Console.BackgroundColor = savedBackground;
        Console.ForegroundColor = savedForeground;
  }
```